# Have a Non-Generic class take a generic argument in constructor

Tags: generics, kotlin

I would like to have a non-generic class in kotlin that uses generics in its constructor in order to specify that a parameter. However, I can't figure out how to do this, and the Java-to-Kotlin converter for Intellij breaks.

My java class looks like this

```
public class Test {    
    interface I1 { }    
    interface I2 { }

    private final I1 mI1;
    private final I2 mI2;

    public <T extends I1 & I2> Test(T host) {
        mI1 = host;
        mI2 = host;
    }
}
```

The converter's output looks like this.

```
class Test(host: T) where T: I1, T: I2 {
    internal interface I1
    internal interface I2

    private val mI1: I1
    private val mI2: I2

    init {
        mI1 = host
        mI2 = host
    }
}
```

I would like to do this because in Android development it is useful to be able to specify a constructor parameter that looks like `<Host extends Context & CustomCallbackInterface>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at Kotlin's [grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#typeParameters), it seems that this is not possible at the moment. For primary constructors, the type parameters denote class type parameters:

> ```
> class (used by memberDeclaration, declaration, toplevelObject)
>   : modifiers ("class" | "interface") SimpleName
>       typeParameters?
>       primaryConstructor?
>       (":" annotations delegationSpecifier{","})?
>       typeConstraints
>       (classBody? | enumClassBody)
>   ;
> ```

For secondary constructors, there are no type parameters possible:

> ```
> secondaryConstructor (used by memberDeclaration)
>   : modifiers "constructor" valueParameters (":" constructorDelegationCall)? block
>   ;
> ```

---

However, a constructor is just a special function. If we instead don't use the constructor, but a function of our own, we can come up with the following:

```
class Test {

    interface I1

    interface I2

    private val mI1: I1
    private val mI2: I2

    internal constructor(host: I1, host2: I2) {
        mI1 = host
        mI2 = host2
    }

    companion object {

        fun <T> create(host: T): Test where T : Test.I1, T : Test.I2 {
            return Test(host, host)
        }

    }
}

fun <T> test(host: T): Test where T : Test.I1, T : Test.I2 {
    return Test(host, host)
}
```

We can now call `Test.create(host)` or `test(host)` to create an instance.

Comment: This is called "a factory".  Would be good to explain the companion object in one sentence.  Also the @JvmStatic annotation which might be good here if they want to call the factory as-if it were a class static.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [nhaarman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675383/nhaarman)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35210527/3255152) you can use [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) to make `Test`'s [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) implement the `invoke` `operator`:

```kotlin
class Test {

    interface I1

    interface I2

    private val mI1: I1
    private val mI2: I2

    private constructor(i1: I1, i2: I2) {
        mI1 = i1
        mI2 = i2
    }

    companion object {
        operator fun <T> invoke(host: T): Test where T : I1, T : I2 {
            return Test(host, host)
        }
    }
}
```

You can then create a `Test` object using the call syntax you want:

```kotlin
Test(object : Test.I1, Test.I2 {})
```

Comment: The issues with this approach is that it isn't a real constructor from the viewpoint of Java or other JVM languages (if that matters), for those the name will be weird if they even find the function (@JvmStatic would help).  And reflection also won't see it as a constructor (again, might not matter).